# Get Elastic BeanStalk Deployment process logs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently working on Elastic Beanstalk hosted app which I have been manually making deployments to staging with the `elbcli` command below

```
eb deploy app-name
```

While this has been previously working well, my current deployment has been erroring out and I would like to view the deployment logs to figure out why this is happening. But all I can get from EB logs is this

[image: AWS EB CLI LOG]

Is there a better way for me to get a deeper dive into the deployment process such as the point at which packages are installed and the app started?

I have tried looking a few of the `ebcli` commands such as `events` and `logs` but all I get is vague results such as the one in the above image.

Comment: I did a lot of debugging a while ago because of some strange npm compilation errors on eb. What helped me a lot was actually ssh'ing into the instances and manually running the installation scripts to see what goes wrong. There, you can either directly run something like `npm i` or check /var/log for problems

Answer (score 3):

From the Elastic Beanstalk console you can click "Logs" from the left-hand side navigation, and click "Request Logs", and select either full logs, or the last 100 lines of the log.  In either case, you want to look for the `/var/log/eb-activity.log` file, and it should contain some information about what the error was.

In these cases I often just find it easiest to ssh into the server and tail the log during the deploy so I can follow along and see where it gets stuck:

```
$ eb ssh my-environment
$ tail -f /var/log/eb-activity.log
```

Comment: And if you don't know what `my-environment` should be, just type `eb list` for the possible environments you have to choose from.